# JSON does not work in ajaxForm

Tags: php, json, ajax, ajaxform

It is just **impossible**. I cannot find what is wrong!!Consider the following very simple `testing code`:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>   <!--AJAX JQUERY FORM PLUGIN-->
</head> 
<body>   

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#form1').ajaxForm({ 
        dataType:  'json',      
        success: function () { 
           alert(5);    
        }            
    });
}); 
</script>

<form action="proceed.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" >
   <input type="submit" name="one_button" id="one_button" value="GO" />
</form>
</body>
```

and the code for `proceed.php`:

```
<?php
  $message= 'success';  
  echo json_encode($message); 
?>
```

The above code does not alert '5' on button click unless I subtract line `dataType:  'json'`. Is the problem in PHP which does not send correctly the json data? I cannot tell... The crazy about that is I have used exactly this code many times and everything was fine!!!

Comment: I'm just curious why you do an ajax call without a `source` or `url` ?

Comment: That is ajax form plugin @Naruto it takes the url from form action

Comment: Ah, apologies, I had no idea, tought it was just an ajax call

Comment: I don't see a json header in php

Comment: your code is fine, make sure your form is submitted.. you can use firebug browser plugin to check error..

Answer (score 1):

Please your $message as array. Your code must be look like this.

```
<?php
  $message[]= 'success';  
  echo json_encode($message); 
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: check in browser's network section , weather your ajax call is working or not. if not than apply the onclick function on your submit button. remove action file name. than give your url in ajax call js code

Answer (score 0):

```
 $message= 'success';
```

must be an array;

```
 $message[]= 'success';
```